# Trying to match URL using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match URL using regex

```
https?:\/\/.*\..*
```

But unable to understand how to end the match if a space occurs after the URL.

For example in the below Image, for last match, i want it to end, before the space.
But nothing seems to be working.

Can you also explain why adding \b (word boundary) at the end doesn't work ?

[image]

Comment: https://www.regexpal.com/94502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the solution below using lazy and a non-capturing group for the last white space:

Look here for far better regex' [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

```js
//well let us dive into this:

var matches = document.querySelector("pre").textContent.match(/https?:\/\/.*\..*/g);

console.log(matches);

/*
your regex does the following
search for http:// or https://
then you want to search for every character that is not a newline until you find a dot
after that you simply search for everything that is not a newline.


you need lazy and a non-capturing group, lazy is ? - (?=\s)
*/

var matches2 = document.querySelector("pre").textContent.match(/https?:\/\/.+?\..+?(?=\s)/g);
console.log(matches2);
```

```html
<pre>
foo@demo.net

http://foo.co.uk/
http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bard
https://mediatemple.net jhjhjhjhjhjh
</pre>
```

Comment: Because `\b` stops on a word boundery and `.` is a such a boundery.

Comment: isn't space considered as word boundary ?

Comment: Yes, but it stops earlier at the first dot.

Comment: https?:\/\/.*\..*\b     ----   this is not stopping at . or space in https://regexr.com/

Comment: Because there is no limit to `.*`, try to make it lazy `.*?`

Answer (score 3):

Just use a `\S`:

```
https?:\/\/.*\.\S*
```

`\S` means: match everything that is not a space char (space, tab, delim..)